# class "Dinosaur" having issues with its positional argument

Tags: python, class, methods, setter, getter

It's giving me an error where I have been indiced and initialized the variable `type` but I don't really find any issues here.

For this task, create a class `Dinosaur` with an instance variable called `_type`.

Create a getter method called `getType()` that returns the dinosaur's type.

Create a setter method called `setType()` that sets its type.

```
class Dinosaur:
        def __init__(self,type):
            self.type=type

        def setType(self,type):
            self.setType=type

        def getType(self):
            return self.type

# Create three dinosaurs
d1 = Dinosaur()
d2 = Dinosaur()
d3 = Dinosaur()

# Set their types
d1.setType("T-Rex")
d2.setType("Velociraptor")
d3.setType("Stegosaurus")

# Print the types
print(d1.getType())
print(d2.getType())
print(d3.getType())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor takes one argument:

```
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type=type
```

So you should create objects with that argument:

```
d1 = Dinosaur('T-Rex')
...
```

Otherwise you get that positional argument error you mention.

Or you could change the constructor to initialize `type` as an empty string or `None` or similar:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.type = ''  # or None
```

Also, there is a problem with your setter, it should be `self.type=type` not `self.setType=type`

Comment: Yes, it works when I create objects with the Argument. but if initialize 'type' as an empty string it still gives me that error

Comment: Make sure you remove the `type` argument from the constructor

Comment: have done that, not trying to say it's a syntax error. by Error I mean there is nothing that shows up on my screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can add default value in your constructor, which makes your arguments optional.

```
class Dinosaur:
    def __init__(self,type = None):
        self.type=type
```

then you can:

```
>>> d1 = Dinosaur()
>>> print(d1.getType()) 
None
>>> d1.setType("T-Rex")
>>> print(d1.getType()) 
"T-Rex"
```

or pass a argument:

```
>>> d2 = Dinosaur("Velociraptor")
>>> print(d2.getType())
"Velociraptor"
```